# How to use "declare" instruction within Spring AspectJ?

Tags: java, spring, annotations, aspectj

I have a bunch of classes inside a Spring 4.2 project.
I'd like to have all of them annotated with @Xyz annotation. According to AspectJ documentation it could be done by

```
declare @type : x.y.z.* : @Xyz;
```

instruction. 
But I have no clue where to place it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some testing on my side and after some struggling, I looked for the concrete implementation. Sadly, `@DeclareAnnotation` exists but is not implemented.

We can see it here.
https://github.com/eclipse/org.aspectj/blob/V1_8_9/docs/adk15ProgGuideDB/ataspectj.xml#L1017

I thought it would be implemented sinced the annotation appeared in version 1.5.3. My bad.

---

**Original answer (not working, AspectJ v1.8.9).**

First you need to enable AspectJ in your configuration. For example, Java configuration :

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class AopConfiguration {}
```

Then you create a new aspect with the `@DeclareAnnotation` annotation :

```
@Aspect
public class XyzAspect {

    @DeclareAnnotation("x.y.z.*")
    @Xyz class XyzClass {}

    @DeclareAnnotation("x.y.z.MyClass.*(..)")
    @Xyz void xyzMethod() {}
}
```

Comment: Looks like it targets a _xyzMethod_ while I'm aiming a class. Trying at the moment 
    `@Aspect
    public class AnnotationAspect
    {
        @DeclareAnnotation("x.y.z.+")
        @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) Object any;
    }`

Comment: I see, it is ruled by annotation value only, not by the attribute applied. Still building..

Comment: Nope - no luck. `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
    <aop:config proxy-target-class="false">
        <aop:aspect ref="annotationAspect"/>
    </aop:config>

    <bean id="annotationAspect" class="x.y.z.AnnotationAspect" />`

Comment: I did some testing on my side and after some struggling, I looked for the concrete implementation. Sadly, `@DeclareAnnotation` exists but is not implemented... my bad. I thought so since it was started since 1.5.3 and we are at 1.8.9...
https://github.com/eclipse/org.aspectj/blob/V1_8_9/docs/adk15ProgGuideDB/ataspectj.xml#L1017